# Data set for Cloud Computing

Tags: cloud, scalability

I am working on scalability in cloud computing, as of now i could not find suitable data set (e.g. One month web request, Online sales)for request prediction or forecasting. Even i tried the UCI data sets and Google cluster data set 2011, but the google link is no more available.

Could you please help to find the more suitable data set (e.g Date, time and number of request).